# Second NotesDocument not saving in For Loop

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a for loop in which I retrieve Notes documents. In this Loop I also change field values. After changing the field value I save the document. The first document is saved and I see the new changes in the document, I also save the second document(which is correctly retrieved according to debugger) but the changes are not saved..

My Cod ( I am saving at: Call docOrderLineTemp.save(True,True) ) :

```
For x = 0 To nrOfOrderResponseLines - 1
        Dim nodeOrderResponseLine As Variant
        Set nodeOrderResponseLine = nodeOrderResponseLineList.Item(x)
        If nodeOrderResponseLine.nodeName = "OrderResponseLine" Then
            Dim nodeDeliveryDateTimeInformation As Variant
            Dim nodeScheduledDeliveryDate As Variant
            Dim scheduledDeliveryDateStr As String
            Dim scheduledDeliveryDate As Variant
            Dim docOrderLineTemp As NotesDocument
            Dim counter As Integer
            Dim nodeItemNoSupplier As Variant
            Dim orderLineStatusCode As String

            Set nodeItemNoSupplier = nodeOrderResponseLine.getElementsByTagName("SuppliersTradeItemIdentification").Item(0)

            Dim searchKeys(1 To 3) As String
            searchKeys(1) = docOrder.ID_Order(0)
            searchKeys(2) = creditorObj.crdnr
            searchKeys(3) = nodeItemNoSupplier.Text
            Print "searchKeys 3 : " + searchKeys(3)




            Set docOrderLineTemp = nvwOrderRegels.getDocumentByKey(searchKeys,True)

            counter = 0
            While Not docOrderLineTemp Is Nothing 
                'Is order waar het omgaat zelfde als gevonden order
                If docOrder.ID_Order(0) = docOrderLineTemp.ID_Order(0) Then
                    'komt artikelnummer en crediteurnummer overeen, als ja dan onderstaand uitvoeren
                    If (nodeItemNoSupplier.Text = docOrderLineTemp.ArtikelnrKlant(0)) And (creditorObj.crdnr = docOrderLineTemp.Crdnr(0)) Then
                        Print "docOrderLineTemp.StatusRegeldocOrderLineTemp.StatusRegel " + docOrderLineTemp.StatusRegel(0)
                        orderLineStatusCode = nodeOrderResponseLine.getElementsByTagName("StatusCode").Item(0).Text
                        If(orderLineStatusCode = "7") Then
                            docOrderLineTemp.StatusRegel = "Waiting for info supplier"
                        Else
                            docOrderLineTemp.StatusRegel = "Order placed"
                        End If

                        'TO DO! checken bij uitlezen orderregel dat orderregel opgepakt wordt adhv artikelnummer en crediteurnummer!

                        Set nodeDeliveryDateTimeInformation = nodeOrderResponseLine.getElementsByTagName("DeliveryDateTimeInformation").Item(0)
                        If Not nodeDeliveryDateTimeInformation Is Nothing Then
                            Set nodeScheduledDeliveryDate = nodeDeliveryDateTimeInformation.getElementsByTagName("ScheduledDeliveryDate").Item(0)
                            If Not nodeScheduledDeliveryDate Is Nothing Then
                                'datum formaat in orderbevestiging is = YYYY-MM-DD
                                scheduledDeliveryDateStr = nodeScheduledDeliveryDate.Text
                                Dim splittedDate As Variant
                                Dim newDate As String
                                splittedDate = Split(scheduledDeliveryDateStr, "-")

                                newDate = splittedDate(2) + "-" + splittedDate(1) + "-" + splittedDate(0)
                                'Duedate is DD-MM-YYYY
                                scheduledDeliveryDate = CDat(newDate)
                                docOrderLineTemp.EerstBevestigdeDatum = scheduledDeliveryDate
                                docOrderLineTemp.ViewEerstBevestigdeDatumBestel = scheduledDeliveryDate


                            End If
                        End If

                        Call docOrderLineTemp.save(True,True)
                    End If

                    Set docOrderLineTemp = nvwOrderRegels.GetNextDocument( docOrderLineTemp )



                    counter = counter + 1


                Else
                    Set docOrderLineTemp = Nothing
                End If
            Wend
        End If
    Next
```

What could be the problem here??

Update: Changed getDocumentByKey to GetAllDocumentsByKey, this made it work.

Comment: Two questions: 1/ did you test with the debugger, and 2/ Why don't you use GetAllDocumentsByKey, in order to get all matching documents in on go as a NotesDocumentCollection?

Comment: Your code has two many levels. Create subfunctions... Do you really need to save the document as a response document ? Is the notesview set to autoupdate ?

Comment: @D.Bugger I checked with the Debugger, everything looks fine the docOrderLineTemp is set with the correct document (correct universal ID) but it does not save.

Comment: I changed getDocumentByKey to GetAllDocumentsByKey and now it works :)